# Avoiding installation of IIS Express 8 during an unattended install of Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Our developers use the full version. Is there something I could specify in `AdminDeployment.xml` or elsewhere to avoid installing IIS Express 8 to begin with, instead of removing it manually afterwards?

Comment: Full IIS and IIS Express do not conflict with each other BTW.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li, the developers do not want to have IIS Express on their machines nevertheless.